# Operations on dynamic arrays

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation, warning-messages

When I do a simple operation like this

```
fib = Table[Fibonacci[i], {i, 15}]
```

and then look to find the position of a certain value, everything works fine:

```
indices = Flatten@Position[fib, _?(# > 99 &)]
{12, 13, 14, 15}
```

However, once I make the table `Dynamic` and try the same thing the position function does not seem to work:

```
Slider[Dynamic@n, {1, 10000, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
fib = Dynamic@Table[Fibonacci[i], {i, n}];
indices = Flatten@Position[fib, _?(# > 99 &)]
{}
```

Upon further investigation the reason seems to be that `Dynamic` turns the `Table` into a nested list (that isn't actually nested, i.e. it still appears as `{"List"}` and not `{{List}})`.

For example, without `Dynamic` `fib[[1]]` returns the first element and `fib[[2]]` returns the second. However, with `Dynamic`, `fib[[1]]` returns the entire list and `fib[[2]]` returns an error that

> Part 2 of {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610} does not exist.

What is going on here and how do I find the position of elements in a Dynamic Table?

Comment: It has become `Dynamic[List[...]]`. Not sure what is your goal but you can: `Dynamic[ fib = ... ; indices = ...]` and later you can use those variables

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `fib` to a `Dynamic` object. Thus its [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) becomes `Dynamic` instead of `List`. Use [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) to see the full structure.

```
FullForm[fib]
```

> `Dynamic[Table[Fibonacci[i], List[i, n]]]`

```
Length@fib
```

> `1`

One can get the current value of the dynamic object `fib` using [`Setting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Setting.html) and avoid making `indices` another `Dynamic` object by putting its assignment inside `Dynamic`.

```
Slider[Dynamic@n, {1, 100, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
fib = Dynamic@Table[Fibonacci[i], {i, n}];
Dynamic[indices = Flatten@Position[Setting@fib, _?(# > 99 &)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @andrewmh20 keep in mind `indices` is not a list here too.

Comment: I edited my answer to make `indices` a `List`.