# How to Operate on a Dynamic Dataset?

Tags: dynamic, dataset, filtering

I cannot operate on the `Dataset` I am dynamically filtering. Minimal example follows.

```
DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}],
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}],
   Module[{},
    current = 
     Dynamic@ds[Select[#"class" == class ∧ #"sex" == sex &]];
    DynamicSetting@current[GroupBy["age"]]
    ]
   }]
 ,
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];}
 ]
```

[image]

I have tried `Setting` instead of `DynamicSetting`. I also tried moving the `Dynamic` into the `Select` on both `class` and `sex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of trouble can be avoided by not setting `current` to a `Dynamic` object, but assigning a value dynamically to it inside `Dynamic`.

```
DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}],
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}], 
   Dynamic[current = ds[Select[#"class" == class ∧ #"sex" == sex &]];
    current[GroupBy["age"]]]}], 
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];}]
```

[image: dds]

By setting `current = Dynamic@ds[Select[#"class" == class ∧ #"sex" == sex &]]` the `Head` of `current` becomes `Dynamic` instead of `Dataset`. If one really wants to do that, one has to use [`Setting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Setting.html) to get its current value (the `Dataset` `[GroupBy["age"]]` should operate on).

```
DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current}, 
 Column[{PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}], 
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}], 
   current = Dynamic@ds[Select[#"class" == class \[And] #"sex" == sex &]];
   Dynamic@Setting@current[GroupBy["age"]]}], 
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];}]
```

[`DynamicSetting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicSetting.html) **is not** the same as `Dynamic@Setting`. I consider `DynamicSetting` to be useful only in conjunction with [Evaluate in Place](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html).

Comment: May you provide a brief description on why this works?

Comment: It is unclear to me why `Dynamic[Setting[_]]` works but `DynamicSetting[_]` doesn't.  I thought that is what `DynamicSetting` was used for.

Comment: I use `Module` as there are several lines of code there and I prefer to contain them in module inside of `Column` as a style point.  Feels cleaner to me.

Comment: @Edmund [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99866/18476) is a simpler version of a similar problem.

Comment: Humm.  I may have over-simplified my example. Should I edit existing or ask a new question. Your answer does not work for: 

`DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}],
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}],
   Dynamic[current = filter[class, sex]];
   current[GroupBy["age"]]
   }],
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
   filter[c_, s_] := ds[Select[#"class" == c \[And] #"sex" == s &]]}]`

Comment: @Edmund My answer does work. You just misplaced one `]`: `DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current}, 
 Column[{PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}], 
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}], 
   Dynamic[current = filter[class, sex]; current[GroupBy["age"]]]}], 
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]; 
   filter[c_, s_] := ds[Select[#"class" == c \[And] #"sex" == s &]]}]`.
Invisible `Dynamic`s don't do anything.

Comment: Ah, I have to write everything that uses the dynamic symbol in one great big `Dynamic`.  That is going to look a bit of a mess.  However, if that is the way it is done.

Comment: Yes!! This works in `DynamicModule` I am developing.  Many thanks. (+1) Will let it sit for a bit: just in case. :-)

Comment: @Edmund A simple and elegant way to separate the big `CompoundExpression` inside `Dynamic` is to use a `DynamicWrapper`: `DynamicModule[{ds, class, sex, current}, 
 Column[{PopupMenu[Dynamic@class, {"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}], 
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@sex, {"male", "female"}], DynamicWrapper[
    Dynamic[current[GroupBy["age"]]],
    current = filter[class, sex];]}], 
 Initialization :> {ds = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]; 
   filter[c_, s_] := ds[Select[#"class" == c \[And] #"sex" == s &]]}]`

Comment: Very nice addition!